# Depth-first vs Breadth-first

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

With my experience, it seems that DFS is much more popular than BFS. For example, DFS is more memory efficient. But I just wanna know when BFS will outweigh DFS? In what certain case, we should prefer choose BFS rather than DFS?

Comment: If you have an infinite graph (with finite degree of each vertex) and the solution is guaranteed to exist, BFS is guaranteed to find it while DFS can well run infinite time

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Infinite graphs don't fit into any physically existing machine though, so this is hardly a case worth considering.

Comment: @delnan Well, technically that's true, you can't have an actually infinite graph, but you can have very large graphs without having to store every node and edge.  For example, a grid of cells is a good example of an effectively "infinite" graph that can be stored in a very sparse way.  So I would disagree with it not being a case worth considering.

Comment: @Kyle But if it's finite, both BFS and DFS will terminate and which one terminates sooner depends on where exactly the start and goal vertices are. A huge but finite graph does *not* automatically translate into an advantage for BFS.

Comment: Sorry, if this question is too broad. But since everyone knows what I really mean and they also give the answers I need, I do not think it is really necessary to modify the question. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of BFS is that it goes by levels, so if you have reason to believe whatever your looking for is in the top nodes BFS is probably better. If your sure it's on the bottoms, DFS might be better since it doesn't take any particular levels first.

The example I remember reading is when looking for medical records, you're more likely to need newer medical records than older ones, which are probably on the bottom on the tree.

Answer (score 0):

For arbitrary graphs there is no such way to prove that which one is better as in some case DFS is more efficient on others BFS is efficient. But for trees you can certainly prefer one over other. For example You are traversing binary tree then , the stack space required by the DFS is `O(logN)` whereas by BFS it is `O(N)` for queue. But if you are using a sparse graph then BFS might use less space then DFS. The time complexity on average is same for both but you might find DFS preferable if solution is present at higher depth from root or BFS if it is closer to the root